# Prove the equivalent condition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Let $X=\sum_{i=1}^N\xi_i$be a compound Poisson random variable, where $N$ is a Poisson random variable with mean 1, and $(\xi_i)_{i\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a farmily of i.i.d. random variables with distribution $\mu$, independent of $N$. Prove hat for any $p>0$, $E|X|^p<\infty$ iff $E|\xi_1|^p<\infty$.

My question: I don't know how to derive the expection of the compound Poisson random variable $X$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: remind that, if $N$ is a RV with Poisson distribution and $x_i$
 represents a set of identically distributed RV that are 1) mutually independent each other, and 2) independent of $N$, the resulting compound Poisson RV $X$ has expectation $E(Y)=E(N)E(X)$.

Comment: what about the power?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** this is based on:
$$
E[g(X)] = E[E[g(X)|N]]
$$
and the estimation
$$
\sum x^p\le 
\left(
\sum x_i\right)^p \le C_p \sum x_i^p
$$

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
E|X|^p &= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}E(|X|^p|N=k) P(N= k) \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}E\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^k\xi_i\right|^p\right) P(N= k) \\
& \leq \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}C\sum_{i=1}^kE\left(\left|\xi_i\right|^p\right) P(N= k)\\
&=  \sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}CkE\left(\left|\xi_1\right|^p\right) P(N= k)
\end{align}

and $$\sum_{k=0}^{+\infty}E\left(\left|\sum_{i=1}^k\xi_i\right|^p\right) P(N= k) \geq E|\xi_1|^p P(N = 1)$$